# Help with passing parameters to a file and fetching the credentials

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I have developed a shell script which takes schema id and password as parameter to login into database using sqlplus,runs a query and mails the result.

Below is the code snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Two input parameters USER_ID and Password
DB_USER=$1
DB_PWD=$2
result=`sqlplus -s $DB_USER@D1TFDDS/$DB_PWD<<EOF
spool sample.txt
sql query
spool off
EOF`
v1_result=`cat sample.txt | sed -e 's/ //g' | tr " " "\n"`
echo "${v1_result}" > mail.txt
mailx -s "Samplemail" abc@gmail.com  < mail.txt
```

In here am passing id and password as parameter to fetch the result.I do not want to pass my credentials to the script,instead can I store it in a .txt file with restricted permission.

And pass say environment id and schema name as parameter to the .txt file which will give me userid and password.

Answer (score 1):

You could `source` a *configuration file*.

In your script you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh

#...

CONFIG="${HOME}/myconfig"

DB_USER=""
DB_PWD=""

if [ -f "${CONFIG}" ]
then
    . "${CONFIG}"
fi

#...
```

which `sources` (reads and executes commands from) a *configuration file* `myconfig` in your home directory, if present with the `dot operator`.

Content of the `myconfig` file:

```
DB_USER="admin"
DB_PWD="insecure"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the credentials in a file like this:

```
SCHEMA:DB_USER:DB_PWD
```

then you can do:

```
eval $(grep "^$SCHEMA:" credentials-file | awk -F : '{print "DB_USER=" $2 "; DB_PWD=" $3}')
```

From then on you can use $DB_USER and $DB_PWD.

Note that this assumes there are no special characters in either DB_USER or DB_PWD field, i.e. characters that are special to the shell such as `;`, `&`, `(` and so on. If there are, you will have to change the `awk` command to add extra quotes.